# How to display EasyAdmin main sidebar?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm using EasyAdmin v3.1 with Symfony 4.4.

My EasyAdmin main menu side bar gets hidden when I'm on a table view, which is very wide (horizontal scroll bars are displayed)

Is there a way to always show the main menu side bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem for one of my client's project so i overrided the easyadmin view templates  and it solved my problem.

```
your-project/
├─ ...
└─ templates/
   └─ bundles/
      └─ EasyAdminBundle/
         ├─ layout.html.twig
         ├─ menu.html.twig
```

in menu you can change the position of sidebar so it won't be hidden. for more information how to override easyadmin template chick this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/design.html#overriding-templates)